# Android development without gradle and with appcompat or share library

Tags: android, android-appcompat, command-line-tool

Build android app from command line without gradle, I tried the following article and working for simple Android App.

[How to make Android apps without IDE from command line](https://medium.com/@authmane512/how-to-build-an-apk-from-command-line-without-ide-7260e1e22676)

But failed while trying with AppCompat layout, tried the following command line but still no luck

```
aapt package --auto-add-overlay -f -m -J $SRC_BASE/build/gen/java -M $SRC_BASE/src/AndroidManifest.xml -S $SRC_BASE/src/res -S /path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res -I /android-home/platforms/android-23/android.jar
```

**ERROR:** (using android-23)

```
/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/values-v24/values-v24.xml:3: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Borderless.Colored'.

/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/values-v24/values-v24.xml:4: error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Colored'.

/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/values-v26/values-v26.xml:15: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name: attr 'android:keyboardNavigationCluster'.
```

even I tried with android-30.

```
${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:9: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:9: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:9: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:9: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintTop_toTopOf' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:31: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:31: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:31: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:31: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'layout_constraintRight_toRightOf' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:9: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf' with value '@id/tv2').

${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res/layout/activity_main.xml:20: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'layout_constraintBottom_toTopOf' with value '@id/tv3').

/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/color/abc_btn_colored_borderless_text_material.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/color/abc_btn_colored_text_material.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/color/abc_tint_btn_checkable.xml:19: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/color/abc_tint_default.xml:19: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/color/abc_tint_edittext.xml:19: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/color/abc_tint_seek_thumb.xml:19: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/color/abc_tint_spinner.xml:19: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/color/abc_tint_switch_track.xml:19: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/color/abc_tint_switch_track.xml:20: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'my.pkg.tst'

/path/to/appcompat/v1.2.0/res/color/abc_tint_switch_track.xml:21: error: No resource identifier found for attribute 'alpha' in package 'my.pkg.tst'
```

Anybody have success with AppCompat and other libraries without gradle, only using pure java, and android sdk tools ? (ant is also fine.)

Build the android app without gradle for simple app without app-compat. The following code is working fine for simple android app.(reference for if anyone interested.)

```
mkdir -p ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/build/gen/java
aapt package -f -m -J ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/build/gen/java -M ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/AndroidManifest.xml -S ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res -I ${ANDROID_SDK_HOME}/platforms/android-30/android.jar
mkdir -p ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/build/classes
javac -d ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/build/classes -source 1.7 -target 1.7 -classpath ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/java:${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/build/gen/java -bootclasspath ${ANDROID_SDK_HOME}/platforms/android-30/android.jar ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/java/jj/android/clb/MainClass.java
dx --dex --output=${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/build/classes.dex ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/build/classes
aapt package -f -m -F ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/build/app.unaligned.apk -M ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/AndroidManifest.xml -S ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/src/res -I ${ANDROID_SDK_HOME}/platforms/android-30/android.jar
cd ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/build
aapt add ${PROJECT_BASE_DIR}/build/app.unaligned.apk classes.dex
 'classes.dex'...
cd ..
zipalign -f 4 build/app.unaligned.apk build/app.aligned.apk
apksigner sign --ks Andorid-KeyStore.jks --in build/app.aligned.apk --out build/app.sign.apk
```